# In probability notation: what does a tilde over a letter mean?

Tags: probability, notation

I am reading [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/juxddtvfvlf51yv/paper/convex.pdf) paper. In section 1.1 he says:

[image]

What do the tildes above the letters mean? How can I translate these two sentences into ordinary English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tilde can have a variety of meanings in different contexts, but as is made clear later in the paper, the tilde over the $p$ is being used there to indicate an empirical probability function (rather than a theoretical model/population probability function) - that is, one made from the sample proportions of each of the symbols.

That's consistent with the definition in the section you refer to.

Comment: so c-tilde y means how many times y is empirically observed?

Comment: That appears to be the definition, yes.